# Xamarin forms implement bottom bar with transparent cutout

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I implement following bottom bar in xamarin.forms. Is there any way to create the bottom bar rather than using .png images? (for the camera we can use the button image)

Please note the transparent space between the bottom bar and camera image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you want it for all there platforms?

Comment: You can use Custom Renderers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: @G.hakim I want for both Android & iOS

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT aware of custom renderer but the challenge is floating like camera button, More explanation would be useful